Extract the numbers interspersed with ‘+’
I have a column in my table in string format that contains different types of discounts:

integers
decimal numbers
compound discounts, i.e. whole numbers interspersed with the + symbol (e.g. 10+3, 5+3+2 etc.). In this case the discount should be interpreted as, in the example 10+3, discount of 10% and then further discount of 3%, which equals a discount of 12.7% (1- 0.9*0.97)

In the third case, how can I extract, one at a time, the numbers interspersed with the + so that I get the total discount?
The problem is that the number of + is variable, there could be one, or two, or none.
Thanks for your help!
Here's the table: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ifu871wh75913qiotpgn7/DiscountFormula.xlsx?rlkey=h3p0o12bvn58wawguxotwu7s1&st=r0il3ew1&dl=0

Is it only ever + characters? Could you have '10+3-2' or '2/3+4'? Will the value always be an integer value, or could you have decimal values? (4.2+1.8')

The separator character is always the ‘+’ and in the case of compound discounts the numbers are always integers.

You are much better off storing the final result rather than (or as well as) the steps to calculate it but if you only have to worry about + and all the values are >= 0 and < 100 then you can use string_split and the trick to simulate a PRODUCT aggregate function.
DECLARE @T table(YourDiscountColumn VARCHAR(100));

INSERT @T VALUES  ('10+3'), ('5+3+2')

SELECT *
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT 1 - EXP(SUM(log(1 - value / 100.0))) AS v
        FROM    string_split(CASE 
                                WHEN YourDiscountColumn NOT LIKE  '%[^0-9+]%' THEN YourDiscountColumn 
                              END, '+')) X(compound_discount)

Or if you don't want to use the logarithm approach and can assume a max number of elements you could also do something like
SELECT compound_discount = 1 -
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[0]')/100.0,1) *
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[1]')/100.0,1) *
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[2]')/100.0,1) *
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[3]')/100.0,1) *
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[4]')/100.0,1) *
       ISNULL(1 - JSON_VALUE(array, '$[5]')/100.0,1)
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY
(VALUES(CONCAT('[', REPLACE(CASE 
                                WHEN YourDiscountColumn NOT LIKE  '%[^0-9+]%' THEN YourDiscountColumn 
                              END, '+', ','),']')))V(array);



Fantastic, in one step it does exactly the calculation I was looking for. Thank you.

Selecting only this year's documents works perfectly, but unfortunately if I apply the formula to the whole table it gives me an error: Error when converting data type from varchar to numeric.
I have attached the table.

From a quick scan down you have values like 3,5 - how are they treated? And also values like 10%

I've updated it so it doesn't try to apply it to any values if they contain characters not in the range 0-9 or a + character. For columns not in that format - e.g. '10%' these will need different logic and probably use COALESCE to combine them
